# Textview and some buttons in column GTK

Tags: linux, gtk, gtk4

I'm trying to create a layout with an text view and in the 2nd column 4 buttons aligned vertically. I tried reading documentation but the window isn't rendered or button stay aligned horizontally.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<interface>
  <object id="window" class="GtkWindow">
    <property name="title">Test</property>
    <property name="resizable">False</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkGrid">
        <child>
          <object class="GtkTextView" id="viewww">
            <property name="overwrite">True</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="monospace">True</property>
            <property name="input_purpose">GTK_INPUT_PURPOSE_DIGITS</property>
            <property name="width-request">400</property>
            <property name="height-request">200</property>
            <property name="left_margin">10</property>
            <property name="right_margin">10</property>
            <property name="top_margin">10</property>
            <property name="bottom_margin">10</property>
          </object>
        </child>

        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton">
            <property name="label">READ</property>
            <packing>
              <property name="left_attach">0</property>
              <property name="top_attach">1</property>
            </packing>
          </object>
        </child>

        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton">
            <property name="label">WRITE</property>
            <packing>
              <property name="left_attach">0</property>
              <property name="top_attach">2</property>
            </packing>
          </object>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

This is an example with packing, but the window isn't rendering anything.
Is this a problem with GTK?

I tried packaging, nested grids but nothing works.

Comment: Which language are you writing the application in? C? Can we see the application code for the window?

Answer (score 0):

Your example seems to be using `packing`, which is only present in GTK3 (btw, the placement of `packing` tag is wrong in your example. It should be within `child`, not `object`). In GTK4, you can use `layout` tag to get similar results.

Example `.ui` file for GTK4 (generated with `gtk4-builder-tool simplify --3to4 window.ui` after applying some fixes):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk" version="4.0"/>
  <object id="window" class="GtkWindow">
    <property name="title">Test</property>
    <property name="resizable">0</property>
    <property name="child">
      <object class="GtkGrid">

        <child>
          <object class="GtkTextView" id="viewww">
            <property name="overwrite">1</property>
            <property name="monospace">1</property>
            <property name="input-purpose">digits</property>
            <property name="width-request">400</property>
            <property name="height-request">200</property>
            <property name="left-margin">10</property>
            <property name="right-margin">10</property>
            <property name="top-margin">10</property>
            <property name="bottom-margin">10</property>
          </object>
        </child>

        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton">
            <property name="label">READ</property>
            <layout>
              <property name="column">0</property>
              <property name="row">1</property>
            </layout>
          </object>
        </child>

        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton">
            <property name="label">WRITE</property>
            <layout>
              <property name="column">0</property>
              <property name="row">2</property>
            </layout>
          </object>
        </child>

      </object>
    </property>
  </object>
</interface>
```

Play with the `column` and `row` values to get the desired output, if you want to change the layout.

For preview save the content to some file, eg:`window.ui` and do `gtk4-builder-tool preview window.ui`